# What are the TCP header features that are included in DoS buffer overflow?

Tags: http, denial-of-service, tcp

What are the TCP header features that are included in DoS attacks? Such as  service type: http, port: 80 and the count, and what else?

I want to know the features that determine the attack so I can write a code in Hadoop mapreduce to extract them from a log file containing TCP packets.

Comment: buffer overflows are dependent on the buffer that is being targeted - so it is difficult to list all possible methods that could be used - however, snort rules will have all this laid out for you - it will be a long list, but it will be all there, just search for dos in the rules

Comment: In my opinion it is unclear what you are asking. For one you are asking about DoS attacks and there is a variety of these. Then you ask about TCP headers for these attacks which restricts the possible DoS attacks. But then you surprisingly ask about buffer overflow which is usually associated with the payload and not with the TCP header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It varies according to the service and the attack. DoS attacks tend to fall into three categories; saturating the network connection (a.k.a. bandwidth flooding), overloading the service (a.k.a. application flooding), or overloading the firewall (a.k.a. firewall flooding).

Network saturation works by sending so much data to the server that it uses up all of the bandwidth, resulting in most genuine users (and most of the attacker's traffic) being unable to reach the server. This can be done in many ways; typically by sending large amounts of UDP or TCP control packets to the server. This will make it difficult for genuine users to reach **any** service on the network that the server is on, and make it difficult for data to get out of any server on that network back to the Internet. Such traffic can be relatively easily detected and blocked upstream, but as the source IP addresses are almost certainly spoofed, it's difficult to track down. The attackers don't need to actually create any network connections, so the traffic doesn't have to have real IP addresses. In a variant of the attack, the attackers spoof the server's IP address to send TCP SYN packets to non-existent services on thousand of servers on the Internet, who then send TCP RST packets back to the server.

Service overloading works by attacking the service specifically, using up resources on the service. This can be done in a variety of ways, but usually it's done by making lots of requests in a very short period of time, using up all of the resources on the server. This might be random logins or anything else that the service is vulnerable to. (Note that other attacks, e.g. brute force hacking of administrative accounts, may produce the same result.) This relies on real network connections, so the source IP addresses are real, but the machines are probably part of a botnet.

Firewall overloading works by opening lots of TCP connections, but not necessarily sending much in the way of data. Firewalls have to handle network connections between networks, and some come with security scanning functions. For the latter to work, they have to monitor the connections. This means that they have to keep details of the connection, and with limited resources, it is possible to use up all of the connections available by opening too many network connections; hence preventing the firewall from accepting any new connections until some of the existing ones time out due to lack of traffic.